# Pass an uploaded image directly from json file

Tags: swift, swift3, stripe-payments

I am trying to upload an image from my app to my heroku backend and then pass that to Stripe for verification. Here is my swift code to upload and pass the image:

```
@IBAction func registerAccountButtonWasPressed(sender: UIButton) {
    let dob = self.dobTextField.text!.components(separatedBy: "/")
    let URL = "https://splitterstripeservertest.herokuapp.com/account/create"
    var imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(photoID,1)
    let params = ["year": UInt(dob[2])! as UInt] as [String : Any]

    let manager = AFHTTPSessionManager()
    let operation = manager.post(URL, parameters: params, constructingBodyWith: { (formData: AFMultipartFormData!) -> Void in
        formData.appendPart(withFileData: imageData!, name: "file", fileName: "photoID.jpg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")
    }, success: { (operation, responseObject) -> Void in
        print(responseObject!)
    }) { (operation, error) -> Void in
        self.handleError(error as NSError)
    }
}
```

I've deleted the list of params above out and left one for readability.

Is there a way to then receive this file and upload it to stripe without having to save it by passing the file parameter? like so:

```
Stripe::FileUpload.create(
  {
    :purpose => 'identity_document',
    :file => params[file]
  },
  {:stripe_account => params[stripe_account]}
)
```

Also in the stripe docs it says to upload the file to 'https://uploads.stripe.com/v1/files' [but then shows code to put in your backend](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/identity-verification#uploading-a-file), does `Stripe::FileUpload.create` do the uploading to stripe for me?

Any insight on either would be great thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to first upload the file to Stripe's API using the ["create file upload"](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_file_upload) call. You can then use the file upload's ID (`file_...`) to [update the account](https://stripe.com/docs/api#update_account)'s [`legal_entity.verification.document`](https://stripe.com/docs/api#update_account-legal_entity-verification-document) attribute.

(This process is explained here:

- https://stripe.com/docs/connect/identity-verification#uploading-a-file
- https://stripe.com/docs/connect/identity-verification#attaching-the-file)

Since the file is provided by the user, you have two choices for creating the file upload:

- have your app upload the file to your backend server, then on your backend, use the file to [create the file upload](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_file_upload)
- create the file upload directly from the app (using your publishable API key), and send the resulting file_upload's ID (`file_...`) to your backend

Here's an example for creating file uploads client-side, using jQuery: https://jsfiddle.net/captainapollo/d8yd3761/.

You could do the same thing from your iOS app's code. Basically all you need to do is send a POST request to `https://uploads.stripe.com/v1/files` with an `Authorization` header with value `Bearer pk_...` (where `pk_...` is your publishable API key) and type `multipart/form-data`, with the file's contents as the request's body. This blog post should be helpful for sending `multipart/form-data` requests using Swift: http://www.kaleidosblog.com/how-to-upload-images-using-swift-2-send-multipart-post-request

Comment: dont suppose you know the answer to my other question? Im still getting to grips with api calls! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41569017/stripe-api-response-the-data-couldnt-be-read-because-it-isnt-in-the-correct-f

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @Ywain I was able to come up with this solution for **IOS Swift 4**. I created the file upload directly from the app and retrieved the *file_upload's ID* to send to my backend to attach to the Connect Account. I did this by importing Alamofire and SwiftyJSON.

```
let heads = ["Authorization": "Bearer \(stripePublishableKey)"]
let imageData = image!.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1.0)
let fileName = "\(NSUUID().uuidString).jpeg"


 Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { multipart in
            multipart.append(imageData!, withName: "file", fileName: fileName, mimeType: "image/jpeg")
            multipart.append(("identity_document").data(using: .utf8)!, withName :"purpose")

        }, to: fileUrl!, method: .post, headers: heads) { encodingResult in
            switch encodingResult {
              case .success(let upload, _, _):
                upload.responseJSON { answer in

                    let value = JSON(answer.value!)
                    let FileID = value["id"].stringValue


                    // Use fileID and Connect Account ID to create params to send to backend.

                    let params: [String: Any] = [
                        "acct_id": ConnectID!,
                        "fileID": FileID,
                        ]

                    print("statusCode: \(String(describing: answer.response?.statusCode))")
                }

            case .failure(let encodingError):
                print("multipart upload encodingError: \(encodingError)")
            }
        }
```